# Is there a program on the Raspberry Pi that can run Windows Programs?

Tags: windows, ubuntu

I was wondering if there was a program for the Pi that can run Windows programs?

In Ubuntu, there's Wine.

But is there a program for the pi?

Comment: I wouldn't say that's a direct duplicate. Wine is not an emulator, and can only run Windows apps on x86 (as this is what Windows apps are compiled for). You'd need a hardware emulator to emulate an x86 architecture on ARM. To be honest, I'd say this is a failing prospect from the start. What are you trying to achieve? Perhaps there is a better way.

Comment: You run .NET applications in Mono - but dont expect to Run Windows Photoshop on the Raspberry. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: I think this is effectively a duplicate since the answers to the other question explain why wine is a no-go on the pi, etc.